# Modify key if it already exists

Tags: perl, hash, key, unique, exists

I'm writing a piece of code that creates a HoAs and loops through for each key. The snippet below shows a basic example of the problem I'm having.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = qw (1 1 3 4 5); # Note that '1' appears twice
my @array2 = qw (a b c d e);
my @array3 = qw (6 7 8 9 10);
my @array4 = qw (f g h i j);

my %hash;   
push @{$hash{$array1[$_]}}, [ $array2[$_], $array3[$_], $array4[$_] ] for 0 .. $#array1;

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    my ($array2, $array3, $array4) = @{$hash{$key}[-1]};
    print "[$key] $array2\t$array3\t$array4\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
[1] b   7   g
[3] c   8   h
[4] d   9   i
[5] e   10  j
```

For the data I'm actually using (as opposed to this example) I have been using a key that I've just realised isn't unique, so, as above I end up overriding non-uniqe keys. I'm mainly using these values as keys in order to sort by them later.

My question is either:

A) I can perform the above task for each key `unless (exists $hash{$array1})` in which case I can modify it

or

B) Is there a way to sort by those values, in which case I could use another, non-redundant key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so, as above I end up overriding non-uniqe keys

You aren't. Let's print out the whole contents of that hash:

```
for my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash) {  # sort numerically!
  for my $array (@{ $hash{$key} }) {           # loop over all instead of $hash{$key}[-1] only
    say "[$key] " . join "\t", @$array;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] a   6       f
[1] b   7       g
[3] c   8       h
[4] d   9       i
[5] e   10      j
```

You would be overriding the values if you were building the hash like

```
$hash{$array1[$_]} = [ $array2[$_], $array3[$_], $array4[$_] ] for 0 .. $#array1;
```

(And printing it as)

```
for my $key ( ... ) {
  say "[$key] " . join "\t", @{ $hash{$key} };
}
```

That is, assigning instead of `push`ing.

If you want to keep the first value assigned to each key, use the `//=` operator (assign if `undef`).

Comment: @FlyingFrog Kind of. Because each hash key can have multiple values, we'll first have to fold that key into the things we actually sort: `my @actual_stuff; for my $key (keys %hash) { for my $val (@{$hash{$key}}) { push @actual_stuff, [ $key, @$val ] } }`. Then, the value from `@array3` is at index 2 of the resulting items: `sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } @actual_stuff`.